# How do I add A Hyphen and numbers to the end of a number or word in excel taking into account the year as well and the number in between the letters?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

Example for the oldest year that matches column A start with -1 and as the years go up add one add+1 and to return column c

```
W1020B 1977 W1020B-1    
W1020B 1978 W1020B-2    
W1020B 1979 W1020B-3    
W1020B 1980 W1020B-4    
W1012B 1981 W1012B-1    
W1012B 1982 W1012B-2    
W1012B 1983 W1012B-3
```

Comment: Is each line in your question a complete cell or is (for example) `W1020B` in on cell, the year in another and `W1020B-1` in a third? Do you want a formula or a VBA solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS to return the number:

```
=A1&"-"&COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,"<="&B1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Also, Can this formula be use to compare a third column? Same concept but if the name matches in column C, return column D. When the name changes for that same number start the count again.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                W1020B 1977 red W1020B-1
W1020B 1978 red W1020B-2
W1020B 1979 white W1020B-1
W1020B 1980 white W1020B-2
W1012B 1981 purple W1012B-1
W1012B 1982 purple W1012B-2